# Issues with SSH

Tags: linux, oracle, ssh, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Issue:  I am trying to SSH from Mac to Oracle Cloud.

Command I am using: ssh -i <private_key_file> username @ public-ip-address

```
               ssh -iv <private_key_file> username @ public-ip-address
```

(-) is minus.

Errors I am getting:

cloud userid Clound instance IP address: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

When I use -iv flag:

SSH could not resolve hostname (it provides my public key): Node name NOR servname provided OR Not Known.

My authority to my public and private keys on my mac is 700.  I tried 400 previously, but I keep getting the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.   Thank you.

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/Tasks/accessinginstance.htm

Comment: If it is showing your key as the hostname, your arguments are out of order. Put `-v` before `-i` then supply your key. And place no spaces around `@`.  Correct syntax is `ssh -v -i /path/to/priv/key user@public-ip`

Comment: The `-i` flag must be followed by the path to the key but you have followed it by a `v` that you'd intended to use as a verbosity flag.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Thanks for your help.  I followed the your syntax and now I am getting this error:  OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to cloud/private_key name.pem port 22.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname cloud/private key. Name pem: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: It is still attempting to use your key path as a hostname. Please update your question to show exactly the command you are typing, obscuring only the username and hostname

Comment: Oh wait a minute, do you have a space in your key's filename? Spaces are very bad news when using the CLI. Put your key file name in quotes if you do. `ssh -v -i "/path/to/private/key.pem" user@host`.  Then try to break the habit of ever putting spaces in filenames you ever plan to use on the command line or in a web server, or various other circumstances.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Thanks you so much for your help and time.  Per your advice, I followed the quotes: ssh -v -i "/path/to/private/key.pem" user@host

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski:   I please see below: debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /public_key.pem
Load key "/path/to/public/_public.pem": invalid format
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
abc@123.456.789.111: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Comment: The error suggests you gave it the public key, not the private key as needed by `-i` but that still might work anyway. Otherwise this means the server is not prepared to accept your SSH key for authentication - i.e. your public key is not listed in /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys on the server or /home/username/.ssh is not 700 or /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys is not 600.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski:  Thank you Michael, I will just keep on trying. I will let you know the results.  Thank you for your kind replies and help.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowsk:  I was able to resolve this issue. I deleted the instance and created a new instance, next , I downloaded new keys.  By following your earlier instructions, I was able to. login without a problem.  Here is the command: $ ssh - i <Private_Key> id@ip_address.  Thank you for your help and patience.  Now that I am logged into the instance, I cannot find or access the oracle DB that I created.  lol.   I will work on that next.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that your <private_key_file> is only readable by you.

`chmod u=r <private_key_file>`

Troubleshoot the DNS issue by specifying the IP address instead of the hostname.

Ensure the remote server accepts connections to port 22 from your public IP address. In corporate settings, this is often not the case and you need to access the public internet either via proxy or a VPN.

Comment: I have rwx authority on my private and public key files, everyone else have no access. 700.     I am using IP address to connect to the oracle cloud instance; as indicated by the commands that I have posted.